# Prevent tweet URLs from being opened by native Twitter app on Android

Tags: javascript, android, url, twitter, titanium

I'm working on an app built in Titanium that has a few "Tweet about this" buttons. Since I can't use the Javascript part of a Tweet button as described in Twitter API, I just use a plain URL with parameters.

On Android, this causes problems. When users click this link, they get a choice how to open it: always the native browser, and additionally any app that has registered for this kind of link. So if the user has the Twitter app installed, Twitter will be shown as one of the options.

That would be great, except the Twitter app is awful. Most types of suggest-a-tweet URL cause the app to crash, and the few that do work don't pass the status text.

I'm looking for a way to force the URL to be opened by the native browser. (Or way to prevent the Twitter app from being among the options presented to the user, but that seems harder to do)

Is this possible using only the URL itself, or maybe a little Javascript? Since I'm using Titanium, Java won't help me.

Comment: The problem is more limited in scope than I thought. The native twitter app that was malfunctioning happened to be outdated on three of the devices we were testing on. Updating the app solved the problem in most use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't give you what you want but give you an alternative suggestion.

What you are trying is hard (often impossible to do without errors) even with native code as your trying to work against the OS. Intents are used in android as a way to let the user decide which program should handle a certain request. If you don't want the user to take this decision I'd suggest opening the url in a embedded browser.

Comment: Thanks for a thoughtful answer. We'll let this sit for a while until we develop a multipurpose full-screen webview that will serve other functions for our app as well.